# gstreamer help message overriding my argparse message

Tags: python, helper, gstreamer, argparse

I'm trying to use argparse to deal with command line arguments to my application, bur I've been having some trouble with gstreamer (which my application uses). When I give the -h option for my application, instead of it showing the help message I defined for the arguments of my program, it show a weird gstreamer help message, omitting the help for my arguments.

I have the following parser definition in my code:

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-c", "--capture", help="Specifies the capture device.\n 0 - Webcam \n 1 - Kinect", type=int, choices=[0, 1], default=0)
parser.add_argument("-i", "--interval", help="Specifies the capture interval in seconds when the auto-capture is on", type=int, choices=[4, 5, 6, 7, 8], default=4)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

and the message I get when I start my program with -h is (my locale is in Brazilian-Portuguese, but it's enough to see the general structure of the help message and the lack of help for my optional arguments)

```
Uso:
  FasTracker.py [OPÇÃO...] - GStreamer initialization

Opções de ajuda:
  -h, --help                        Exibe opções de ajuda
  --help-all                        Exibe todas as opções de ajuda
  --help-gst                        Exibir opções do GStreamer
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a way to supress the Gstreamer help message?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does --help-all print your options as well?

Comment: I have the same problem. Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Not yet phaedrus, unfortunately. Haven't tried --help-all yet! as soon as I have access to the code again, I'll try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had the same problem. I am using ubuntu 10.10 + python 2.6 + python-gst0.10 package.

Finally I tracked down the bug to this: `import gst` before `parser.parse_args()` modifies `sys`. To reproduce, put the following code into `main.py`:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    import argparse, sys
    pparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='my program')
    pparser.add_argument('--plot', action='store_true', default=False, help="Show a plot")
    pparser.add_argument('--log', action='store_true', default=False, help="Write log output")
    pparser.add_argument('filename', action='store', type=str)
    import gst
    args = pparser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
```

and run `python main.py -h`. This produces the following buggy output:

```
Usage:
  main.py [OPTION...] - GStreamer initialization

Help Options:
  -h, --help                        Show help options
  --help-all                        Show all help options
  --help-gst                        Show GStreamer Options
```

If we remove `import gst` (or move the statement after `parse_args`), then the output is correct:

```
usage: main.py [-h] [--plot] [--log] filename

my program

positional arguments:
  filename

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --plot      Show a plot
  --log       Write log output
```